# dbms_lob and utl_file are thrown as vulnerabilities in ADO CD , is there any workaround for this?

Tags: azure-devops, sonarqube

Azure Devops CD is throwing vulnerability for **dbms_lob** and **utl_file** in sonarqube report , is there a workaround to handle this?

Comment: It's recommended to share your `pipeline definition` snippet, and show the `screenshot` of the `log` where it throws as vulnerability. In addition, you can try to add `sonar.exclusions=**/*files` in `SonarCloudPrepare@1` extra properities([link](https://docs.sonarsource.com/sonarcloud/advanced-setup/analysis-parameters/#settings-stored-in-database)), [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qaaqh.png)